# How to make a user to be counted as an "Active user" in facebook app

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am testing my server's login integration with Facebook but I am always hitting the hourly rate limits of Facebook during automation.

I don’t have actual end users so I have created 5 test-users to test (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/test-users). During automation, I am always getting rate limited at 200 api calls per hour.

After some research, I found out that Facebook calculates limits based on "active users" and new logins (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/advanced/rate-limiting/), but I am not clear on who qualifies as "active users". I could not find clear documentation on how Facebook identifies active user.

Is there any way through graph api to make test-users to be counted as "active users" as to avoid hitting by rate limits?

Suppose if I have some actual end users, how to make them counted as active users?

Comment: No there is no way to bypass the rate limiting by using test users.

Comment: @WizKid can I make a existing user active by using the page access token?

Comment: The idea with active users is that they are active. Not that you do something to make them active.